# Viewing both problems with input also jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

When I try to log in password or username you will see it with error logging so I click ok on both the password and username to get my php error until around that no content is user name and password.

The problem is: It comes up and says **"error**" on PHP code! and if there is no content in my input,

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.login').on('click', function(){
    if (logind() === true){
    }
  });
});

var logind = function(){
  if ($('#brugernavn').val() === ''){
     alert('Husk Brugernavn');
      return false;
  }

  if ($('#pass').val() === ''){
    alert('Husk password');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

**PHP**

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, rank FROM bruger WHERE brugernavn = ? 

AND adgangskode = ?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $brugernavn, $adgangskode);
    $brugernavn = $_POST["email"];
    $adgangskode = sha1($_POST["adgangskode"]);


    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $rank);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $count = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();

    if($count > 0)
    {
        echo "log ind now,";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="login" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" id="login">
    <p>Brugernavn</p>
    <input type="email" id="brugernavn" name="email" class="loginbar" placeholder="Brugernavn (Email)">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="adgangskode" class="loginbar" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log ind" class="click login" style="float:left;">
    <div id="sendpassword">
        <a href="/send-password/">
            <img src="/img/send-password/send-password.png" alt="send-password" title="Send Password">
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Echo out $count to see what's being returned.

Comment: @Braunson what you mean??